# ChannelId and uploaded videos id relation in youtube data api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have send request to get my subscriptions in youtube.
I have received subscriptions, which contain [snippet with resourceId containing channelId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#snippet.resourceId.channelId).

I used channelId to get default uploaded video playlist id via [get channels request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22contentDetails%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22UCsAw3WynQJMm7tMy093y37A%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%7D#try-it) to get [contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads).
And i have found out that in all cases contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads is almost the same as channelId.

For example:
channelId is U**C**sAw3WynQJMm7tMy093y37A
uploads playlist id is U**U**sAw3WynQJMm7tMy093y37A

The questions is, is it safe not to send request for playsListID and mutate channelId into playsListID by changing first "UC" to "UU"?

Another question is, can I be sure, that channelId and uploads playlist id are constant for channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question no. 1:**

> [...] is it safe not to send request for playsListID and mutate channelId into playsListID by changing first "UC" to "UU"?

Indeed your observation is true. In my experience using the API, I never came across a channel ID that would not be related to its its corresponding uploads playlist ID by:

`s/^UC([0-9a-zA-Z_-]{22})$/UU\1/`.

But this fact is of an *observational nature only*, because the API *does not document as such the relation* stated above. That means that, even if the relation above holds true today, it may well be that (upon an API implementation change) tomorrow it'll be false.

A compromise towards the simplicity of obtaining an uploads playlist ID from a given channel ID by the `s///`-relation above would be the following: query the `Channels.list` endpoint for to obtain the uploads playlist ID of a given channel *only once* and store that association *forever.*

The *query once, store forever* statement is correct in the light of the answer to your second question.

**Question no.2:**

> [...] can I be sure, that channelId and uploads playlist id are constant for channel?

Yes, you can be 100% sure that once a channel was created and until the YouTube site and its API exist, the ID of that channel and the ID of the uploads playlist of that channel *will not change.*
The IDs of channels that cease to exist *are not reused* for to identify newly created channels.